# Jquery ui error "undefined is not a function"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, jquery-ui

I am using jquery ui. and the code is hosted in [Here](http://mebindevcart.in:2368/get-intersection-point-of-two-linked-list/.)

On opening the console one can see the error "`undefined is not a function`".

I am unable to find the reason for the same. We tried the same code in local machine(that is localhost), without any other theme, and it worked fine.

The below js we have included

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

I am using ghost blogging platform built on node js. The theme being used is casper. 
Will be thankful for any kind of help or pointer to this problem that I am facing.

Thanks Again,

Mebin

Comment: have you try with `http://www.ajax...`?

Comment: @diEcho I have added www. to the code and it still does not work :(. The code hosted has the update that you have suggested.

Comment: @user3258644 you can safely remove `www` - it's not the issue. While second jQuery including `<script src="/public/jquery.js?v=b9f058cf2f"></script>` at `footer` can really be a problem.

Comment: @user3258644 - put your code into `<head></head>`

Comment: Your tabs() function is not defined, and you call it somewhere: $ ( "#tabs" ).tabs(); Maybe some other javascript is missing, or has a local adress?

Comment: @aldanux placing `<script>` in body doesn't cause problems: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3zkhgsyv/)

Comment: @user3258644 have u included your jquery1.11.1 like this 
http://www[dot]ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>'

Comment: @Regent - A `<link>` tag can occur only in the head element

Comment: @aldanux ok, but I still suppose it doesn't affect scripts. And OP has problems with scripts now. And yes: I agree that this stuff should be placed in `<head>`.

Comment: @Regent, thanks that solved it. :),  src="/public/jquery.js?v=b9f058cf2f"></script> was causing the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Regent, pointed out the problem in the comments, src="/public/jquery.js?v=b9f058cf2f"> in the footer was causing the problem.

Comment: It's a good idea to move answer from comments to normal answer, yes. You can also marked it as correct one.

Comment: +1 Yes it is. As per Site standards After one or two days Mebin can accept his own answer. Until that he will not get an option to accept an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think [in your Page](http://mebindevcart.in:2368/get-intersection-point-of-two-linked-list/) which is having the below code. But there is no `Jquery` library get imported.

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    $ ( "#tabs" ).tabs();
  });
</script>
```

These links are broken: **Actually its not importing the Scripts**

```
<script src="http://www.ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://www.ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

[Click to check your likn of jquery.min.js](http://www.ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js)

[Click to to check your likn of jquery-ui.css](http://www.ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css)

[Click to to check your likn of jquery-ui.min.js](http://www.ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js)

[image: Click on the Highlighted link in the Console]

**Modify your src cdn web links like below:** Remove `http://www.` and Put ``

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Links are actually correct. You can see it in my [mentioned fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3zkhgsyv/)

Comment: Its not loading the Jquery libs. Go to page View Source and click on the `src links` in your browser. Thats why you are getting `undefined` error here `$ ( "#tabs" ).tabs();`

Comment: well... It looks like OP changed links on site some minutes ago, because originally links were correct (links were as mentioned in question)

Comment: Links at the site [for example, this](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js) are again correct right now, but error persists. That's what I'm talking about.

Comment: I got the problem. [Check this link](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide#jquery) and give the `src` with out `http:`. Which is mentioned in this link.

Comment: Yes, it's one more way to write link for including jQuery. Nevertheless, original links mentioned in question are also valid. And about this question: problem was solved in question's comments.

Answer (score -1):

You have a function in your `<script>`

```
$(function() {
$ ( "#tabs" ).tabs(); //console shows you have error on this line
});
```

Try putting it inside `document.ready()`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$ ( "#tabs" ).tabs();
});
```

Also your code is outside `<head>` tag. Try placing it inside `<head>` tag.

Comment: `$(function() {})` is equal to `$(document).ready(function() {})`, so answer is deadly incorrect.